# Foreach in 2D arrays with SQL statement

Tags: php, sql

I have a 2D array as follows:

```
Array(
[1] =>  Array
      (
        [0] => 15956,3
        [1] => 15984,0.13
        [2] => 15940,1
      )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15918,0.5
        [1] => 15970,0.5
        [2] => 15902,0.5
        [3] => 15943,0.5
    )
```

How would i integrate a foreach loop to go through each child of the array and generate a dynamic sql statement...eg:

```
UPDATE main_stock SET on_hand -= 3 WHERE Rcode = 15918
UPDATE main_stock SET on_hand -= 0.13 WHERE Rcode = 15984
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can compose these values as a temp table or a subquery, then join the two tables with `UPDATE` like this:

```
UPDATE main_stock m
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 15956 AS Rcode, 3 on_hand
   UNION ALL
   ...
) AS t ON m.on_hand = t.on_hand 
SET m.on_hand -= t.on_hand;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $subArr) { // Goes through each array of the main array
    foreach ($subArr as $val) { // Goes through each sub array's values
        $sql = "UPDATE `main_stock` SET `on_hand` = 3 WHERE `Rcode` = " . $val;
    }
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`$iar` is the input array.

```
foreach( $iar as $tar )
    foreach($tar as $line)
    {
        list($id,$value) = split(",",$line);
        mysql_query("UPDATE main_stock SET on_hand -= $value WHERE Rcode = $id");
    }
```